# Formula for $ (I+\varepsilon A)^{-1} = ?$

Tags: matrices

Is there a formula to
\begin{equation}
(I+\varepsilon A)^{-1}
\end{equation}
in terms of $A^{-1}$ or $A$, where $I$ is the identity  matrix $A$ is an invertible matrix and $\varepsilon$ is a constant?

Comment: http://www.emis.de/journals/AUA/pdf/26_815_paper11-acta27-2011.pdf

Comment: You may want to search for the keyword [*Neumann series*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $ \epsilon$ is a small quantity you have  \begin{equation} (I+\epsilon A)^{-1} =I-\epsilon A +O(\epsilon ^2) \end{equation}. This can be easily verified directly:
\begin{equation}
(I+\epsilon A)(I-\epsilon A)=
I +\epsilon A-\epsilon A+ \epsilon ^2 A^2=I+\epsilon ^2 A^2
\end{equation}
so the answer is indeed accurate up to order $\epsilon$.

Comment: To get the answer to higher order use the geometric series as Squid suggested: \begin{equation} (I+\epsilon A)^{-1}=\sum _{k=0}^n (-1)^k\epsilon ^k A^k +O \left(\epsilon^{n+1}\right)=I-\epsilon A+ \epsilon ^2 A^2 -\epsilon^3 A^3 + \ldots +O \left(\epsilon^{n+1}\right) \end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

It's not precisely what you're asking about but if $A$ is any matrix with standard norm $\| A \| < 1$ then geometric series essentially applies

$$(I - A)^{-1} = I + A + A^2 + A^3 + ...$$

Answer (score 0):

there is example of article

http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aml.2005.04.004

which  talks about pertubation matrix inverse,it may help you,please try to download it,it is free,it is given that matrix is perturbed by some another matrix,but it may help you